# How to show cfinclude template in dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion, dialog

I have problem with displaying my page that is included in my template. I set a div tag with an id. Inside I have my cf include that has my test.html page. That div is hidden. So after I click on the link I want to display my page in dialog box. Here is my current code:

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="chkLink()"> Click Here</div>

<div id="bDialog" style="display:none"><cfinclude template="test.html"></div>
```

JavaScript code :

```
function chkLink() {
    $("#bDialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width:750,
      modal:true,
      cache: false,
      load.('<cfinclude template="test.html">'),
      buttons: { 
        "Ok": function () { 
          $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried this code but that gave me an error: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal html:'<head>`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CFINCLUDE runs as a part of the request. It will execute WHEN the page loads not after the fact through a JS function. What you probably need to do is something like "load.('test.html')" ... which would execute another HTTP request for the file.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: no prob. glad to help